# "Proper" Way to Write a SocketIO Client in Rust?

Tags: rust, socket.io

I've made an effort to be succinct, but this is probably several questions in one.

I'm writing a small client program in Rust to talk to a SocketIO server which, in my head, is modeled as follows:

- Open connection,
- Send auth credentials,
- Wait for success response,
- Send query,
- Wait for response,
- Print out response info,
- Close connection and exit.

I'm using the `rust_socketio` crate to do all the network stuff, leaving me to just handle the events via callbacks.  And setting the whole thing going is merely:

```rust
fn ev_open (payload: Payload, client: RawClient) {  /* handle open */ }
fn ev_close (payload: Payload, client: RawClient) {  /* handle close */ }
fn ev_login_response (payload: Payload, client: RawClient) {  /* handle LoginResponse */ }
fn ev_query_result (payload: Payload, client: RawClient) {  /* handle AccountQueryResult */ }

fn main()
{
    let socket = ClientBuilder::new (URL)
               .namespace ("/")
               .opening_header ("origin", HEADER_ORIGIN)
               .on ("error", |err, _| eprintln! ("socketio error event: {:#?}", err))
               .on ("open", ev_open)
               .on ("close", ev_close)
               .on ("LoginResponse", ev_login_response)
               .on ("AccountQueryResult", ev_query_result)
               .connect()
               .expect ("Connection failed.");
    /* ... */
```

It seems simple enough, except...

...How am I actually *meant* to use this?  In the model offered by `rust_socketio`, there's no sequencing, no waiting -- any event can happen at any time, and your callbacks will be invoked when the corresponding event arrives.  Okay, cool, so: What should I be doing when nothing else is happening, and how do I *do* that?

The way I currently have this set up is:

- Inside the `ev_open()` callback, emit the login request,
- Inside the `ev_login_response()` callback, emit the "AccountQuery",
- Inside the `ev_query_result()` callback, print out the results, then `std::process::exit()` the program.

Let me list the confusions I have:

- Confusion #1:  `ClientBuilder::connect()` doesn't block; it returns immediately.
  I have to wait for the "open" (a/k/a "connect") event to arrive before I can `emit()` my requests; otherwise I get an error response.  This would make more sense if I were using the async features, but I'm not.  If I don't do something after the `.connect()` call to stall execution, `main()` will exit and the socket will be destroyed.  Right now, after creating the socket, I'm calling `std::thread::sleep()` in a loop, which is a messy hack.
- Confusion #2:  Callbacks can't return anything.
  They can't return `Result`s from possible missing or malformed data, which seems... weird.  How do you propogate errors out of the callbacks?
- Confusion #3:  Who is actually invoking my callbacks?
  The docs say a thread is spawned to receive socketio messages and invoke callbacks, but I can't find where in the crate this actually happens.
- Confusion #4:  `socket.disconnect()` *hangs* if I attempt to call it from inside the `ev_query_result()` callback.  *Bwuh?*

I have a feeling I'm missing some fundamental concept here, some way of thinking about this kind of program that will cause it all to suddenly make sense.  Feedback gratefully accepted.

Comment: The thread is spawned in `Client::new()`, in `Client::poll_callback()`. (https://docs.rs/rust_socketio/latest/src/rust_socketio/client/client.rs.html#210)

Comment: Thank you; I finally grok the polling sequence.  I've also satisfied myself there's no way for callbacks to return *anything.*  It's increasingly looking like I'm expected to set up channels to push status/results back up to `main()`.